# How can I list all registered arguments from an ArgumentParser instance?

Tags: python, argparse

Couldn't find any existing method for it so I wonder if there is a hack?

Comment: `.add_argument` returns the argument (Action) that it just created.  So you can save that in your own variable or list.  Those are the same object pointers that you see in the `._actions` list.

Comment: Could someone explain the negative votes?  Is it just that the question is too short?  Or is there something wrong with it - in the context of `argparse`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a hack; you can list all registered actions using the undocumented attribute `parser._actions`:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('spam')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='spam', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('eggs')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='eggs', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser._actions
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None), _StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None), _StoreAction(option_strings=['--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None), _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='spam', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None), _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='eggs', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

Using the attribute is at your own risk; these internals are subject to change in future versions.