# Change Python Argparse delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am using a Python script as an intermediate application. The main application which I don't have access to the code is passing arguments to the Python script in this format:
`"-number+1"` (argparse would work fine if the argument was `"-number 1"`).

Any idea how to make Argparse taking that value (1) from that argument similar to what it could be done if there was no `"+"` but space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be too naive, but you can simply split each incoming argument on `+` to produce a list more suitable for `parse_args` than the original `sys.argv`:

```
# Turn ["-number+1"] into ["-number", "1"]
processed_args = []
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg.startswith(tuple(p.prefix_chars)):
        process_args.extend(arg.split("+", 1))
    else:
        process_args.append(arg)
args = p.parse_args(processed_args)
```

On second thought, don't split anything. Just replace the first `+` with `=`:

```
args = p.parse_args([word.replace("+", "=", 1) if word.startswith(tuple(p.prefix_chars)) else word for word in sys.argv[1:]])
```

`argparse` already knows that the single word `-number=1` is the same as the two words `-number` and `1`.

Comment: Is it necessary to add ``sys.argv[0]`` after the splitting again?

Comment: No; `parse_arg` parses `sys.argv[1:]` if its argument is `None` (which is the default argument value).

Comment: Could also check if `word` starts with one of the registered actions and split at the first `+` to make it less naive

Comment: This is a good approach, thanks. but yeah there are other arguments which have been passed regularly with space and I don't want to break them.

Comment: It just occurred to me that replacing the *first* `+` only in each word with `=` might be sufficient. E.g., `-number+1` becomes `-number=1`, which `parse_args` already understands. Oh, and only make the replacement in words that start with an `argparse` prefix character.

Comment: The prefix-character thing is true for deciding which words to actually split; I'll have to update the answer either way.

Comment: @PeLa Nothing would affect arguments containing spaces; each is already its own word in `sys.argv` and I am/was not splitting on whitespace, only `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688009/843953), you could check if `word` starts with one of the registered actions and split at the first `+` to make it less naive.

Let's say you have a set of actions like so:

```
actions = {'-hello', '-number'}
```

Alternatively, you could define `actions` [using the `_actions` attribute of the parser object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881456/how-can-i-list-all-registered-arguments-from-an-argumentparser-instance). This is an internal attribute, so it might change in the future.

```
actions = {o for a in parser._actions for o in a.option_strings}
```

```
# Turn ["-number+1"] into ["-number", "1"]
args = p.parse_args([word for arg in sys.argv[1:] for word in arg.split('+', 1) if arg.split('+', 1)[0] in actions])
```